# I cannot find Haml.tmLanguage on Sublime Text 3

Tags: ruby, sass, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime text 3.

When I make scss file, that is named to filename.scss.haml Automatically.
This issue easily solving this link(http://tosbourn.com/sublime-text-reading-sass-files-as-haml/)

but I cannot find "/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Rails/Ruby Haml.tmLanguage." files and .../Packages/Rails Directory is not exists...

How can I fix that problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using sublime text 3.

http://tosbourn.com/sublime-text-reading-sass-files-as-haml/ says look in:

> /Library/Application Support/**Sublime Text 2**/Packages/Rails/Ruby Haml.tmLanguage.

Wrong version, so I guess the fix to your problem would be use ST2 maybe?  Or find a more updated reference.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found another solution https://coderwall.com/p/ijpp-w in Sublime Text 3. but my Identity path is ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/... but I cannot found "Rails" Directory in Packages directory.

Answer (score 0):

Open a sass file
View > syntax > open all with current extension as... > SASS